# Collision Detection in Python OpenGl

Tags: python, opengl, collision-detection, breakout

Collision Detection in Python OpenGl

I'm working on breakout game by using python opengl and I want to make collision detection between the ball and the bricks (Without using pygame).

I tried a lot but I couldn't and I didn't find any tutorials about it (using Python OpenGl).

How can I add collision detection in it?

My code until now:

**deleted the code because the problem is solved and the whole project is changed (the code wasn't good)**

Comment: How is this not a dupe of [the last one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62253612)?

Comment: I edited the last one (to add the code) after it's been closed, so I decide to delete it and ask a new question.

Comment: See [Issue finding side of collision for Circle-Rectangle collision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61718259/issue-finding-side-of-collision-for-circle-rectangle-collision). The algorithm uses `pygame.math.Vector2`, but that can be changed with ease.

Comment: cannot be deleted.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I wanna delete it or delete the code

Comment: @Rabbid76 The main problem was that I wanted to make the collision according to the x and y axis but it was better to create a method that checks the collision between any two objects (rectangles) with the model parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problem.
I used a different architecture for the whole project and I could link my data structure with the new architecture.
The idea was not using any library, just data structure.